# how can i get run time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote the code to receive data from the device using serial communication device with window.

I can see Continuous data in Console window in eclipse and save data in txt file.

Data transfer continues until the port is disconnected

I want to see time that Data is transmitted .

Finally, I want to get a time-data graph , so Time data is needed

How do I write code? The code below is the code I wrote

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
   , routes = require('./routes')
   , user = require('./routes/user')
   , http = require('http')
   , path = require('path');

var app = express();
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var UrlParser = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

 // development only
 if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
 }

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
     });                                            

var port = new SerialPort("COM32" , { 
     baudRate:9600,
});

port.on("open" , function(){                
     console.log('open success'); 
});

port.on('data', function(data) {            
    converted_data = parseFloat(data);
    console.log(converted_data);    
    fs.appendFile('TestDB.sql',converted_data + '\r\n',function(err) {
        if(err) 
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log('data->db');
    }); 
});

port.write("mon 1\n", function(){           
    console.log('write to device');
});

app.get('/data', function (req,res) {       
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/data.html');
```

Comment: what's the problem? To make a graph, you need to save a dataset and convert that to a graph

Comment: @Ben problem is that i need runtime data ( function execute time) . How to get time ?

Comment: use `new Date` or `moment` node module